# Are ther situations when 3 points do not lie on a circles?

Tags: proof-writing, circles

Consider 3 points on a plane, points are real. Is it possible that the points are placed in a way that makes it impossible to draw a circle trough them.

- I know that if the point forms a line then its not a circle (unless we allow for a circle with a infinite radius to pass trough the points). But are there any other cases?
- I know there are cases where theres more than one solution, such as when 2 or 3 of the points are the same.

Now i understand that the three point circle forms 2 triangles and therefore I think there does not exist cases other than points being in the line that dont work. But how do i build a proof out of this?

[image]

Can i use the fact that a normal to a point in between the points allways has a intersection somewhere if they are not perpendicular. And then just state that this only happens if the points form a line?

Comment: If $A,B,C$ are not collinear, then the bisectors of the line segments $AB$ and $BC$ are not parallel. Therefore those bisectors intersect and...

Comment: If three points in a euclidean plane do not lie in a straight line they are the vertices of a triangle. Every triangle has a circumcircle which is the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of the sides. Take the bisectors of two sides - these intersect in a point. It is then obvious that the bisector of the third side (which is also the locus of points equidistant from the relevant vertices) passes through the same point,

Comment: http://www.mathopenref.com/const3pointcircle.html

Comment: Thank you, i just needed to be exceptionally sure about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments ( and in your add to the question) we have a simple geometric solution of this problem simply noting that the axis of two non aligned consecutive segments always intersect in a point that is the center of the circumference passing through the extremes of the segments . You can find also an analytical solution noting that a circumference passing through three points: $A=(x_A,y_A)$, $B=(x_B,y_B)$, $C=(x_C,y_C)$ has an equation $x^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0$ such that:
$$
\begin{cases}
ax_A+by_A+c=-x_A^2-y_A^2\\
ax_B+by_B+c=-x_B^2-y_B^2\\
ax_C+by_C+c=-x_C^2-y_C^2
\end{cases}
$$
that is a system in the unknowns $a,b,c$. We can show that this systems has no solutions if the three point are on the same line and has infinite solutions if at least two points coincide.

Comment: Yes, thanks for making an answer, we dont want zombie posts. Thing is i have currently a bit flakey network connection and i needed to comit to reference. I didnt think anybody would answer between my 2 minute edit but somebody beat me with few seconds. Added image i drew for a post i did earlier.